# Does Puppeteer have sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, puppeteer

We're trying to create integration tests for our cordova app and puppeteer seems to be a good way to launch the ui. 
But since we're using the sqlite database, it's very important for us that puppeteer also supports that option. 
Does anyone know whether puppeteer has an integrated sqlite database? I do know it has localStorage.

Answer (score 1):

Puppeteer is just a driver for the chrome headless. It doesn't support sqlite, You can use indexDB. Otherwise since it's all nodejs, you can simply store everything on sqlite using the [sqlite3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3) driver.

Some helpful functions for accomplishing your target will be the [exposeFunction](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageexposefunctionname-puppeteerfunction) function.